# How to get a good edge flow

Tags: modeling, loop

See the image below: why does the edge flow stop here?

[image: screenshot of Blender showing a non-looping Loop Cut pre-visualization]

I know the face is a bit distorted, but is this the reason, or is there something else happening?

The below is it fixed not sure why its fixed but, I'm happy I guess.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Loop Cut* (assuming that's what you're trying to do here) only works on quads, so the problem is likely that the faces the cut won't loop through are not actually quads.

What you can try to fix it, is to remove the current faces that don't get looped, and recreate them (by selecting only 4 polygons and pressing <kbd>F</kbd>). Then the *Loop Cut* operation should work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and i was about to try it if the problem was not already solved? I had done some.... I don't know what you call it, i cant post an image? Basically there is a way to convert 4 faces that is side by side into 2 faces side by side and 8 faces to 4 and then 4 to 2  after i had done this the loop suddenly went all the way around?

Comment: @nathanholmes You basically joined the faces? In any case, I guess ultimately it turned the faces into quads. Perhaps there was an accidentally doubled vertex somewhere, and one of them was part of one face, and the double was part of another. Anyway, glad to hear it's solved :)